# Modification of Minkowski sum

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image]

As shown in the illustration, there are two regions A and B, each consists of a set of vectors. For each vector (point) in A, you can pick a vector (point) in B and find there middle point (i.e. the vector obtained by halving the sum of the two vectors from A and B respectively). My question is, how do I generate and visualize the region consisting all possible middle points generated by all possible combinations of vector pairs from A and B. On top of that, if we account for the possible overlappings (the same middle point generated by different vector pairs), the resultant region can be thought of as a probability distribution of all possible combinations. Is there a way to obtain/visualize this distribution?

Edit: I looked it up. It should actually be half if their Minkowski sum. The distribution part I am still not sure though. The reason that I want to consider distribution is that, the typical Minkowski sum does not account for which point in the summed up region is formed by how many pairs of vectors from A and B, since it is a set. I want to consider the situation where even if A and B are 'uniform', the sum will account for the multiplicity of each element (in the sense a modification of Minkowski sum to be a multiset)

Comment: To get help in this forum it's important that you show your work on the problem. For example, have you tried calculating this sum for simple shapes? It shouldn't be hard to calculate some examples of you choose the sets simple enough.

Comment: I have tried some simple examples. Unfortunately even for shapes as simple as squares I am not able to get any useful insights... the reason being the cardinality of A and B are both infinite, therefore it is hard to visualize. the only insights I have so far is the multiplicity is not equal for each element if you sum up all possible pairs.

Comment: What you are looking for is a convolution (w.r.t. abelian group $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) of $1_{A}$ and $1_{B}$ - uniform distributions on sets $A, B$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples using Monte Carlo method:

Two segments

[image]

A segment and a square

[image]

A square and a disk

[image]